# Como posso traçar um espectrograma em tempo real lendo dados de um ADC como o "MCP3008" conectado a GPIO da Raspberry?

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, matplotlib, numpy, scipy

Minha ideia serea ler dados de um ADC como o MCP3008 conectado a GPIO da Rasperry, a partir das leituras plotar um gráficos em tempo real do sinal processado por uma FFT(transformada rápida de fourrier) ou STFT (tranformada curta de fourrier)

Exemplo
[image: STFT]

Obrigado

Códigos Usados: Geração do Gráfico em tempo Real

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

dt = 0.01
Fs = 44000.0              # sample rate
timestep = 1.0/Fs         # sample spacing (1/sample rate)
t = np.arange(0, 10, dt)  # t range
n = 256                   # size of the array data
w = 10000                 # frequency of the input

data = np.sin(2*np.pi*w*t)



def update(data):
    # update the curves with the incoming data
    line.set_ydata(data)
    #line2.set_ydata(magnitude)

    return line,

def generateData():
    # simulate new data coming in
    while True:
        nse = np.random.randn(len(t))
        r = np.exp(-t/0.05)
        cnse = np.convolve(nse, r)*dt
        cnse = cnse[:len(t)]
        data =  np.sin(2*np.pi*w*(t)) + cnse
        magnitude = np.fft.fft(data)/n
        magnitude = np.abs(magnitude[range(n//2)])
        yield data

fig = plt.figure()

# plot time graph axis
timeGraph = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
timeGraph.set_ylim(-0.2, 0.2)
timeGraph.set_xlabel('Time')
timeGraph.set_ylabel('Amplitude')

# plot frequency graph axis
freqGraph = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
freqGraph.set_xlabel('Freq (Hz)')
freqGraph.set_ylabel('|Y(freq)|')

# get frequency range
n = len(data) # length of the signal
print(len(data))
k = np.arange(n)
T = n/Fs
freq = k/T # two sides frequency range
freq = freq[range(n//2)] # one side frequency range

# fft computing and normalization
magnitude = np.fft.fft(data)/n
magnitude = np.abs(magnitude[range(n//2)])


line, = timeGraph.plot(np.linspace(0, 1, len(t)), 'b')
line2, = freqGraph.plot(freq, magnitude, 'g')


# animate the curves
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, generateData,
                              interval=10, blit=True)

plt.show() # open window

leitura do ADC:

        while True:
    # Read all the ADC channel values in a list.
    values = [0]*8
    for i in range(8):
        # The read_adc function will get the value of the specified channel (0-7).
        values[i] = mcp.read_adc(i)
    # Print the ADC values.
    print('| {0:>4} | {1:>4} | {2:>4} | {3:>4} | {4:>4} | {5:>4} | {6:>4} | {7:>4} |'.format(*values))
    # Pause for half a second.
time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Agora que traduziu, qual é o problema em questão? Você apenas descreveu o que pretende fazer, mas não disse o que fez até agora e qual foi o problema encontrado.

Comment: Oi Anderson 

Eu usei para estudar e como exemplo o código abaixo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41009258/how-to-plot-2-animated-graphics-with-x-axis-fixed-in-matplotlib-with-subplots

Consigo fazer a leitura dos sensores ligados ao MCP3008
     
    # Hardware SPI configuration:
    SPI_PORT   = 0
    SPI_DEVICE = 0
    mcp = Adafruit_MCP3008.MCP3008(spi=SPI.SpiDev(SPI_PORT, SPI_DEVICE))

No entanto não consegui integrar ambos em uma só solução, para inserir a leitura do sensor no gráfico e no calculo FFT.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione qualquer código que está utilizando diretamente nela.

Comment: mais fácil fazer uma pergunta simplificada como estou usando o MCP3008  assim e da esse erro.